# No solution working for cors and cloud function

Tags: cors, gcloud

I am having an issue with CORS and cloud functions.  I have read and tried every solution posted everywhere starting with reading the docs and am perplexed.  Here is my entry point for the cloud function currently:

```js
exports.entryPoint = (req, res) => {
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    const query = req.body.searchTerm;
    getData(query).then(data => {
        const result = formatData(data)
        res.send(result)
    })
}
```

This is how the docs say to do it with another way for preflight checks including:

```js
if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    // Send response to OPTIONS requests
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    res.set('Access-Control-Max-Age', '3600');
    res.status(204).send('');
} else {
    res.send('Hello World!');
}
```

None of this works for me.  I have read and tried using

```
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true})
```

That route has proven no success.  The error I receive is "Access-Control-Allow-Origin missing".  Inspecting the headers in the browser there in fact has never been any response headers relating to cors show up within all the solutions I've tried.  My only thought is I have res.set in the wrong place?
Thank you.

Comment: Please update your question's summary to reflect your question

Answer (score -1):

Please be aware of the options that you are setting, if you are doing `POST` request this also should be included. [Mozilla documentation  `Preflighted request`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

```js
exports.entryPoint = (req, res) => {
    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        // Send response to OPTIONS requests
        res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS'); // CHANGED
        res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
        res.set('Access-Control-Max-Age', '3600');
        res.status(204).send('');
        return; // ADDED
    }
    // ACTUAL RESPONSE
    const query = req.body.searchTerm;
    getData(query).then(data => {
        const result = formatData(data)
        res.send(result)
    });
}
```